# A case of code plot in C++

Tags: listings, code, program

I am entering some C++ files inside my LateX main.tex, and it appears that LateX "writes" the space symbol when there's a space in a string inside listing. (I am using listingsutf8 package) [image: Spacing C++]

Is it possible to make it look like a normal space? Just like *Serial.print("Nuevo valor de consigna: );*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showstringspaces=false` should fix your problem.

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @AdriánMudarraMartín: Don't forget to upvote and accept it (after you have enough reputation to vote).